# Typescript conditional extends with nested object

Tags: typescript, extends

I am building a type that checks if a member of a class-type is an object and if so, a specific type must be assigned. I provide a more explanatory example below.

Here we have the class example we are going to use.

```js
declare class myObject {
    name?: string
    id?: number
    parent?: {
        child: number
    }
}
```

Here we have the type i am trying to make

```js
type myType<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends {[k:string]:any} ? T[K] : "something"
}
```

It should check that `parent` member is in fact an object of that type and allow something like this

```js
const example: myType<myObject> = {
    parent: {
        child: 0
    },
    name: "something"
    id: "something"
```

But it doesn't because `parent?` doesn't get checked successfully against `{[k:string]:any}`. This happens because `parent?` is an optional member. If i change `parent?` to `parent` it works as expected. To try and work around this I tried switching `{[k:string]:any}` with `{[Z in keyof T[K]]?: T[K][Z]}` but i observed the same exact behaviour.

A link to [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEkoGdnwLYE8DyAjAVuAC7YAORAlgPYB2UE8A3gLABQ8H8d6IA-AFzxkRGBRoBzNp3gVgArgFd0uEDCmdSsEDSLyW7aZzAALChGCCaSlWoMcAvm0es2oJHETRUGHAWIA5WjJKWnomdQ5uPkFhUQkImTlLa1UEzTgdQX1DI1NzZOVUu3hnZzYiTFIELAAVSpAAHhqAPngAXnDigG0AaRkaeABrEEwqADN4GoBdeRreqfgQAA8ibWA0Ri7B-lixcSnBKBpMe3heSfn4QQAiZCoeIlMJa6c2NjBaYXhV4WDqOggglq9QaWDwhDAJHI-3orQ62Q0WkyTHgAHpUfAGgBaLHwACiMBgVBgAEIEtITGYLPAAIwJewAGgSURudweT3E1yZxVkrPuIEeexerDKrA+NC+PyIgRof1CgJ8dSqoN8EOlQWh8rhnWk6W0RCyaIx2NxgXxhOJADpybkqYI6cVGcyoDw+eyhdzpLz4Ld+YLnq9WEA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right when you say this happens because `parent?` is an optional member.

But what does it mean to be an optional member?

In JS it means the property can either have a value or be undefined.

In TS, it means that the type of `parent?` is actually something like:  `{[k:string]: any} | undefined`

The code below solves the error on the linked TS playground.

```
type myType<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]?: T[K] extends ({[k:string]: any} | undefined) ? T[K] : "something"
}
```

Comment: Another issue! If `T[K]` is an array it cannot be assigned to "something", here is a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEkoGdnwLYE8DyAjAVuAC7wDeAsAFDw3wB2U6IA-AFzzJEwCWdA5lVrxuwNvQCu6XCBgBtALrwA9EvgAeALQbhAM3hEAFtzR8QRNGANR+IYPoD28AER1J0mE-0GEMmPZjwwPYgyHQA5CT2YGDiMIK0AA6wIHRE7BTUQrSW3BDA7K5SMvE0AL5U5ZRURJgJCFgAKrUgag0AfPAAvGQl8LIA0sJ08ADWIJj2eg3yYg0DiiAAHkQpwGgAFKSyI6ycPPzy7NaYpfAAPvDidKA6vLYAlPDM8HP9iuxOyPZMhrx8ThUqFQwPY6Jx9CE0hhME06mosHhCGAiB1uhkhEk4Kl0vBekIcnl2ABGXqlAA0vQYTA+Xx+Rn4TgpmRoIhp3zM9P+ylUmm0vn88G8cHg0jAUHEyAQImEaEm+maEiKcnkgMoQA)

Comment: Honestly, I don't think this is a problem with the given solution, you actually changed the original problem. (without updating the question) As you know `number` is a primitive value, but `number[]` is an object. This completely changes the problem. Please create another question, and add the link here, and I'll gladly provide a new answer to your new problem.

Comment: You are right. Here is the [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72927738/typescript-array-checked-as-kstring-any)!

Comment: Answered to the other question, please comment on my answer, if the new given solution does not solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, then you can do the following:

```
type MyType<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends {[k:string]:any} | undefined ? T[K] : "something"
}
```

The `?` gives the property the possibility to be `undefined` (optional), therefore you can replace `{[k:string]:any}` with `[k:string]:any} | undefined`.